# How to redirect from rules with no old values laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So i know it's weird and but I'm trying to make custom validation rule in laravel for a password so that the new password can't be the same as the old one when i try to change my password but I want to empty the fields when i redirect back so i don't want any old values for security purposes to fill the inputs for that exact validation only but the others can redirect back and fill the old values easily so how can I do that with the custom rules

Comment: You choose what fields you want to be filled in your form by using `old()` in your .blade.php file. Just don't use it in any inputs if you don't want to

Comment: @apokryfos I want the old value of that input in other validations thats a custom rule i don't want it if that validation only fails not others

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is ask the user to enter their current password (for Security purposes obviously) and the new ones, check if password field matches their current password if so, evaluate the new password string against their submitted current password.

you can also Preg match it to check if they are similar to some extent, eg. have the same characters but misplaced.

> NB: Laravel cannot (rather should not be able to) cross check the
> passwords, you have to explicitly match them.

Comment: Thats not the problem here, i wanted to make the validation come back with empty old values at this exact validation and free the session from that validation at this rule only but in the other rules it can come back with my old values of the input field in the session

Comment: well in that case maybe you can use the [back](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#creating-redirects) method like `return back()->withInput()`

Comment: You don’t understand my case well enough.. i have a custom rule for validating with other validations on the same input i want that when that only rule fails it comes back without old values so the old values will be empty, but in the other validation rules it comes with the old values that’s the case here i hope you got it

Comment: Unfortunately i can't comprehend the case you're implying to, can you please update the question with how the response is now and how you want it to be in each use case for ex. Case 1 request and response and Case 1 request and expected response

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this before redirecting back:

`$request->session()->forget('_old_input');`